# Problem with executing laravel migrations on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my laravel application using Elastic beanstalk, and I need to execute `php artisan:migrate` command on the remote database.
Based on [Maximilian's](https://youtu.be/ISVaMijczKc?t=1363) tutorial I created init.config file inside .ebextensions with contents:

```
container_commands:
    01initdb:
        command: "php artisan migrate"
```

The status of the deployment is Healthy, but it didn't create any table!
any clues, please?

Answer (score 0):

run **php artisan config:cache** then run migrate command

Answer (score 0):

As you did not include any relevant logs. I am guessing you need to run your migration within the staging folder.

An example of how you can run migrations:

```yaml
  04_run_migrations:
    command: "php artisan migrate --force"
    cwd: "/var/app/staging"
    leader_only: true
```

- --force is needed cause php artisan migrate asks you if you are sure to run it on a production environment
- leader_only is needed if you use horizontal scaling.

Source:
https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb/blob/master/.ebextensions/01_deploy.config